# How to fix unknown timezone Pytz on a Raspberry Pi?

Tags: timezone, raspberry-pi3, pytz, apscheduler

I am getting a large traceback error on my Pi3, Pytz can't seem to set the local time. How should I go about solving this?

Here's the line that I think is the issue:

```
    line 181, in timezone
    raise UnknownTimeZoneError(zone)
pytz.exceptions.UnknownTimeZoneError: 'SystemV/EST5EDT'
```

Here's the traceback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "unexpected.py", line 202, in <module>
    sched = BackgroundScheduler()
  File "/home/pi/Documents/flask_projects/unexpected_two/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/apscheduler/schedulers/base.py", line 82, in __init__
    self.configure(gconfig, **options)
  File "/home/pi/Documents/flask_projects/unexpected_two/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/apscheduler/schedulers/base.py", line 121, in configure
    self._configure(config)
  File "/home/pi/Documents/flask_projects/unexpected_two/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/apscheduler/schedulers/background.py", line 29, in _configure
    super(BackgroundScheduler, self)._configure(config)
  File "/home/pi/Documents/flask_projects/unexpected_two/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/apscheduler/schedulers/base.py", line 689, in _configure
    self.timezone = astimezone(config.pop('timezone', None)) or get_localzone()
  File "/home/pi/Documents/flask_projects/unexpected_two/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tzlocal/unix.py", line 131, in get_localzone
    _cache_tz = _get_localzone()
  File "/home/pi/Documents/flask_projects/unexpected_two/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tzlocal/unix.py", line 70, in _get_localzone
    return pytz.timezone(etctz.replace(' ', '_'))
  File "/home/pi/Documents/flask_projects/unexpected_two/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pytz/__init__.py", line 181, in timezone
    raise UnknownTimeZoneError(zone)
pytz.exceptions.UnknownTimeZoneError: 'SystemV/EST5EDT'
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[The SystemV time zones](https://github.com/eggert/tz/blob/master/systemv) are usually not included in various distributions of the tz database.  It would be quite odd to expect [Unix System V](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UNIX_System_V) proprietary constructs to work on a Raspberry Pi.

Indeed, if one exports the `all_timezones` list (in any environment) - you will not find the `SystemV` time zones in there.  Pytz does not include them.

I suggest you take a look at the [List of TZ Database Time Zones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones) to choose a more reasonable time zone.  For example, if you meant Eastern Time as observed by the United States, then you should use `America/New_York` instead.

Comment: Ok thanks. What's the best way to change that timezone? Do I export it out of my .profile? Do I use raspi-config? dpkg-reconfigure tzdata ? Just do it in the actual program ?

Thanks for your response. This is just the first time I've hit a snag like this.